# A little insight on my date conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have been working on the query below, and with some insight from members here I finally got it to run without errors.

My problem now is I need to adjust the date parameters for my YTD columns 2013 and 2012.
This query below worked fine before I tried to adjust the YTD columns.

```
Select CLINIC_ID,SUMMARY_CATGRY,ENTRY_TYPE,
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 1 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jan12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 2 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Feb12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 3 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Mar12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 4 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Apr12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 5 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [May12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 6 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jun12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 7 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jul12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 8 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Aug12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 9 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Sep12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 10 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end)[Oct12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 11 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end)[Nov12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 12 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end)[Dec12],
**SUM(case when EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2012YTD],
SUM(case when EntryYear = 2011 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2011YTD]**
From
(
    SELECT [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].CLINIC_ID, 
        HR_FINAN_CLASS.SUMMARY_CATGRY, 
        [TABLE_LAYOUT].ENTRY_TYPE, 
        datepart(month,[entry_date]) EntryMonth,
        datepart(year,[entry_date]) EntryYear,
         ENTRY_AMOUNT as [sumofentry_amount] 

 FROM [TABLE_LAYOUT]
 Inner Join

(
SELECT [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].CLINIC_ID, OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.CHARGE_CLASS,[GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER, [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD, OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN, OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE, SUM(ENTRY_AMOUNT) AS ENTRY_AMOUNT 

FROM
OUTPAT_REGISTER
Left JOIN
OUTPAT_BILL_REF
ON(OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_BILL_REF.PATIENT_NUMBER)
AND(OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD = OUTPAT_BILL_REF.REGISTRATION_CD)

Left JOIN
OUTPAT_ACCT_REC
ON(OUTPAT_BILL_REF.PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.PATIENT_NUMBER)
AND(OUTPAT_BILL_REF.BILL_REFERENCE = OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.REFERENCE_NUM)

Left JOIN
    (
SELECT CLINIC_ID, PATIENT_NUMBER, REGISTRATION_CD
FROM OP_VISIT_HISTRY
GROUP BY CLINIC_ID, PATIENT_NUMBER, REGISTRATION_CD
--ORDER BY CLINIC_ID
)AS [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID]

ON(OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER = [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER)
AND(OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD =[GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD)

GROUP BY [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].CLINIC_ID,OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.CHARGE_CLASS,[GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER,[GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD,
OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE,OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN

HAVING OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE >'12/31/2010'
)AS [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1]

On([TABLE_LAYOUT].ENTRY_CLASS = [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].CHARGE_CLASS)

Inner Join
OUTPAT_REGISTER

On([Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER)
And([Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].REGISTRATION_CD = OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD)

Inner Join
OUTPAT_AREA_CDS
On(OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTER_AREA = OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REGISTER_AREA)

Inner Join
HR_FINAN_CLASS
On(OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN = HR_FINAN_CLASS.FINAN_CLASS_CD)

Where OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REG_AREA_TYPE <>'RE'
        and datepart(year,[entry_date]) in (2011, 2012)
) src
group by CLINIC_ID, SUMMARY_CATGRY, ENTRY_TYPE
```

I need the YTD 2013 and 2012 columns to have another date parameter, so I switched my YTD syntax to the below, and I get this error

> *Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1/1/2013' to data type int.*

I would like to use this type of date parameter only for YTD **"> = '1/1/2013' and Entryday <= '1/31/2013'"**

```
Select CLINIC_ID,SUMMARY_CATGRY,ENTRY_TYPE,
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 1 and EntryYear = 2013 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jan'13],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 12 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Dec'12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 11 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Nov'12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 10 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Oct'12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 9 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Sept'12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 8 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Aug'12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 7 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jul'12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 6 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [Jun'12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 5 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [May'12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 4 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end)[Apr'12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 3 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end)[Mar'12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 2 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end)[Feb'12],
SUM(case when EntryMonth = 1 and EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end)[Jan'12],
**SUM(case when Entryday > = '1/1/2013' and Entryday <= '1/31/2013' then 
[sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2013YTD],
SUM(case when Entryday > = '1/1/2012' and Entryday <= '1/31/2012' then 
[sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2012YTD]**

From
(
    SELECT [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].CLINIC_ID, 
        HR_FINAN_CLASS.SUMMARY_CATGRY, 
        [TABLE_LAYOUT].ENTRY_TYPE, 
        datepart(month,[entry_date]) EntryMonth,
        datepart(year,[entry_date]) EntryYear,
        datepart(day,[entry_date])  Entryday,
         ENTRY_AMOUNT as [sumofentry_amount] 

 FROM [TABLE_LAYOUT]
 Inner Join

(
SELECT [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].CLINIC_ID, OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.CHARGE_CLASS,[GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER, [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD, OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN, OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE, SUM(ENTRY_AMOUNT) AS ENTRY_AMOUNT 

FROM
OUTPAT_REGISTER
Left JOIN
OUTPAT_BILL_REF
ON(OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_BILL_REF.PATIENT_NUMBER)
AND(OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD = OUTPAT_BILL_REF.REGISTRATION_CD)

Left JOIN
OUTPAT_ACCT_REC
ON(OUTPAT_BILL_REF.PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.PATIENT_NUMBER)
AND(OUTPAT_BILL_REF.BILL_REFERENCE = OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.REFERENCE_NUM)

Left JOIN
    (
SELECT CLINIC_ID, PATIENT_NUMBER, REGISTRATION_CD
FROM OP_VISIT_HISTRY
GROUP BY CLINIC_ID, PATIENT_NUMBER, REGISTRATION_CD
--ORDER BY CLINIC_ID
)AS [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID]

ON(OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER = [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER)
AND(OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD =[GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD)

GROUP BY [GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].CLINIC_ID,OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.CHARGE_CLASS,[GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].PATIENT_NUMBER,[GROUPING_OF_CLINIC_ID].REGISTRATION_CD,
OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE,OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN

HAVING OUTPAT_ACCT_REC.ENTRY_DATE >'12/31/2011'
)AS [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1]

On([TABLE_LAYOUT].ENTRY_CLASS = [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].CHARGE_CLASS)

Inner Join
OUTPAT_REGISTER

On([Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].PATIENT_NUMBER = OUTPAT_REGISTER.PATIENT_NUMBER)
And([Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].REGISTRATION_CD = OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTRATION_CD)

Inner Join
OUTPAT_AREA_CDS
On(OUTPAT_REGISTER.REGISTER_AREA = OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REGISTER_AREA)

Inner Join
HR_FINAN_CLASS
On(OUTPAT_REGISTER.PRIMARY_FINAN = HR_FINAN_CLASS.FINAN_CLASS_CD)

Where OUTPAT_AREA_CDS.REG_AREA_TYPE <>'RE'
        and datepart(year,[entry_date]) in (2012, 2013)
) src
group by CLINIC_ID, SUMMARY_CATGRY, ENTRY_TYPE
```

Comment: You should try to **reduce your problem** to the absolute minimum possible to show to us. This is just **way tooooo much** code and stuff to wade through......

Comment: consider taking the single quotes out of your aliases.  Jan13 is better than Jan'13

Comment: Hopefully, once you get it to work you are going to rewrite it in such a manner that all those hard coded values are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you are trying to compare `Entryday`, wich is a number (1 to 31), with a date, that's why you get an error. You actually don't need that column at all, you can just do:

```
SUM(case when EntryYear = '2013' AND EntryMonth = 1 
    then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2013YTD],
SUM(case when EntryYear = '2012' AND EntryMonth = 1 
    then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2012YTD]
```

Comment: Lamak, your example worked perfect for me. I just needed to add in EnrtyMonth = 1. So simple, yet I could not figure it out.      Thank you very much.                                                             Are there any books you can recommend to expand my knowledge on SQL Server? I have been using SQL Server since September of last year and really struggle with complex queries.

Comment: @Lamak This code will not return the YTD for the entire 2012 and this will only work for 2013 if you want to return only January, which is not the intention of the OP.  The final part of my answer will return the correct result. In order for it to work, you have to remove the `EntryMonth`

Comment: @bluefeet I agree with the YTD for 2013, the values are hardcoded. But your way to calculate YTD for 2012 is wrong, it is calculating the whole 2012, when the real objective is to compare it with the same time amount that YTD 2013, so it should actually be limited to that period of time

Comment: @Lamak I guess it is a syntax issue, because YTD is not typically limited by month.  YTD includes all months up to present. :)

Comment: @bluefeet Yeah, you are right about that definition for YTD. But it is widely used to compare performance on this year, with the same amount of time on previous years

Answer (score 0):

`Entryday` is going to be an integer[(see here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx), and that is why you are getting an invalid cast. You should perform your comparison against the entire `entry_date`.

You could also do a compare of `EntryYear = 2013 AND EntryMonth = 1 AND EntryDay IS BETWEEN 1 AND 31`. However, if you are comparing the entire date, then I would use the first option of checking against the date rather than each part.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Entryday` is an `int` and you are comparing it to a datetime which will not work. The [`DatePart(day, entry_date)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) returns an numeric value between 1 and 31.

Instead of using `datepart(day,[entry_date])  Entryday`, then you should just use the `entry_date`:

```
SELECT [Non_Recurring_Clinic_Step1].CLINIC_ID, 
    HR_FINAN_CLASS.SUMMARY_CATGRY, 
    [TABLE_LAYOUT].ENTRY_TYPE, 
    datepart(month,[entry_date]) EntryMonth,
    datepart(year,[entry_date]) EntryYear,
    [entry_date],
     ENTRY_AMOUNT as [sumofentry_amount]
```

Then when you are getting the totals you will use:

```
SUM(case 
      when entry_date > = '1/1/2013' 
        and entry_date <= '1/31/2013' 
      then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2013YTD],
SUM(case 
      when entry_date > = '1/1/2012' 
        and entry_date <= '1/31/2012' 
    then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2012YTD]
```

But to get the YTD values you really only need:

```
SUM(case when EntryYear = 2013 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2013YTD],
SUM(case when EntryYear = 2012 then [sumofentry_amount] else 0 end) [2012YTD]
```

Comment: Thanks blufeet once again for chiming, but user lamat suggestion of using EnrtyMonth = 1 did work for me. I assume your > and < method would work too as that is the route I was going, but my syntax was probably wrong.                                                    Are there any books you can recommend to expand my knowledge on SQL Server? I have been using SQL Server since September of last year and really struggle with complex queries.

Comment: @user2026836 If you want `YTD` then including the `EntryMonth` will not work once you try to run this query for more than the month you have including. If you don't want to use the `>=` or `<=` values, then you can use the last part of my answer, which checks the `EntryYear` only.  If you only what `YTD` totals, then you should just check the year.